# How to check whether the android device can connecto to the network or not?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, connection

I am a beginner in Android programming, I am trying to make Http requests to a remote server and I would like to check whether the user can connect to the net or not in order to avoid my app to crash due to the fail of an AsyncTask I am making.

I found this method:

```
 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
 }
```

But when I try to call it inside the doInBackground AsyncTask method implementation the app crashes:

```
 class RemoteThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(IMieiDati.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Caricamento...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... strings ){
        // checking whether the network is not available
        // but the app crashes here
        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Log.d("Message", "No Network Connection. Aborting.");   
        } 

       // here I should make the request if the network is available
    }
            ...etc, etc...
```

How can I resolve and e.g. show a message to the user that says something like "We are sorry, in order to use the app properly, you should connect to the network" or anything like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it will better to check for network before executing the `RemoteThread` class. 
And also make sure you've added permissions to you application

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Also check that your are importing right package 
`import android.content.Context;`